# How to show/hide elements on boolean value on react,js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I work with Carousel view, and i have some dynamicaly elements, which should appear from Json list.

```
{
        category: "Category",
        code: "421313",
        title: "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.",
        price: 156,
        sold: false,
        salePrice: false
      },
```

As u can see i have two boolean value, and if thi value true i need to show some div element on the view.

```
               <div className={classes.card_ceromented}>
                Recommended
                </div>
              <div className={classes.card_top_product}>
                Top Product
                </div>
```

> classes.card_top_product this element i need to show hide on bollean value.

How i can show div element on `true` json value?

My code: [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qunzorez/1d3Lzk58/3/)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do conditional rendering .

```
{ category.sold && (<div> This gets rendered when sold is true</div>)}
```

[Conditional Rendering In React](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html)

Comment: I just havef few errors in console ```Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.```

Comment: you should add a ```key={A UNIQUE PROPERTY HERE}``` to the parent div under ```.map()```

Comment: Im doing a similar thing but then in my catergory.sold is 0 so I see 0 on the screen and not the content following it